# Hover Hover textbox remains fixed when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a search bar such that when a user hover overs a button a textbox will appear. What I want to do is keep the text box visible once the user has pressed the text box. So if the user accidentally removes the mouse over the text box or button whilst typing the text box remains in the same place.

Here's my code:

**js**

```
$('form').hover(function () {
   $('input[type="search"]').show();
}, function () {
   $('input[type="search"]').hide();
});
```

**css**

```
input[type="search"]{
display: none;
}

.search-style {
   width: 30px;
   height: 25px;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-image: url(http://localhost/themes/wp-    content/uploads/2015/04/saerch.png); 
  }
```

**html**

```
  <form>
   <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search goes here"/>
   <button class="search-style"></button>
   </form>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need `focus` (I think) and not hover then..

Comment: Looks like a verbatim copy paste of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110309/hover-textbox-remains-fixed-when-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including this CSS:

```
input[type="search"][style]:focus{
   display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the input control in focus event:

```
 $('input[type="search"]').focus(function(){
     $(this).addClass('active');
 })
```

Then, when hiding, you can check if the input is active `.hasClass('active')`:

```
$('form').hover(function () {
    $('input[type="search"]').show();
}, function () {
   if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
      $('input[type="search"]').hide();
});
```